# Youtube API Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function

Tags: jquery, api, youtube

I have no idea why this function does not work.

I am using now a very simple example on my website which basically stops the video once I click on the link. See code below:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<a href="#" id="pause">Pause</a>
```

And thats the script I am using in the bottom of the page:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '315',
        width: '560',
        videoId: 'bpOR_HuHRNs',
    });
    document.getElementById('pause').onclick = function() {
        player.stopVideo();
    };
}
```

Once I click on the Pause link. I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function

I have tried to implement the whole code from google docs: 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Same problem..What is wrong here??

Answer (score 0):

On the link you provided, the tag.src is different than yours. It looks like it should be

```
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
```

while yours is

```
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
```

Maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the problem.. If someone will come across the same error, check if you are using another scripts, like in my case i used reembed.com websites script to make YouTube video as a custom player. That messed up entire YouTube's API

Answer (score 0):

I also have got a such problem.

```
Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function
```

I utilized `tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"` and I have tried to implement the whole code from google docs: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started but have got the same problem.

I've worked with page for `Drupal 9`, and have figured out that for correct working of `youtube API` it should be called the function `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` at the end of the main `Drupal.behaviors.MyBehavior`. It have look like:

```
Drupal.behaviors.playYouTubeVideos = {
  attach(context) {
    .........
    ....main_code_here....
    ......

    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady();
  }
};
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```