# Stop youtube video playing after tab exit

Tags: jquery, youtube-api

I've been looking into ways to stop a youtube video from playing after I leave a tab. The problem is all the solutions I've found require me to add in the video using jquery. Like below.

```
var player;  
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
     }
   });
 }
```

With the limitations of my environment, I do not have this ability. 
There's an unknown amount of videos that are added to each page, there could be 1, 2 or 10 it depends.

I need a way to stop the video from playing when I switch tabs to one not displaying the video.

My set up is as follows

```
<div class="tabs-content">
  <div id="panel-1" class="tabs-panel">CONTENT</div>
  <div id="panel-2" class="tabs-panel">
    <iframe type="text/html" id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l2cANlMm_OI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <iframe type="text/html" id="player" type="text/html" width="640" height="390" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/l2cANlMm_OI?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    /* There could be more than this */
  </div>
</div>
<a class='change-tab' href="#"></a>
```

And my script which I think is close but I get this message "Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function"

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var stopVideos = function() {
      $('#panel-2 iframe').each(function(i, el) {
        if(!window.YT)
        return;

        var player = new YT.Player(el);
        player.stopVideo();
      });
    }
    $(".change-tab").on('click',function() {
      stopVideos();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the solution was due to this line not working

```
var player = new YT.Player(el);
player.stopVideo();
```

After changing it to the following line it worked perfectly

```
el.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
```

So the final code is this

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var stopVideos = function() {
      $('#panel-2 iframe').each(function(i, el) {
        if(!window.YT)
        return;

        el.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'pauseVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
      });
    }
    $(".change-tab").on('click',function() {
      stopVideos();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a small snippet that I use for such use cases. I've wrapped it up in a function for you.
The support and reliability is limited. Browsers can fire tab focus/blur when they detect it i.e. user switching to another tab in the same browser window or when the window was minimised.
OS level events like, when you open a another window on top of browser window (without minimising it, which the browser will detect), that is outside the scope of browser. The simplest example would be that of a user going go his second monitor and bringing in some other application in focus.

In any case, here is the function

```
    function onWindowFocusAndBlur() {
      var hidden, visibilityChange;
      if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
      } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
      } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
      }

      function handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document[hidden]) { // Tab doesn't have the focus
          // Pause the video here
          $('#panel-2 iframe').each(function(i, el) {
            if (!window.YT)
              return;

            var player = new YT.Player(el);
            player.stopVideo();
          });
        } else { // Wohoo, the tab is in focus
          // Play the video
        }
      }
      if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
        // Sadly the browser doesn't support this functionality. Damn legacy support

      } else {
        // Now that we have the support, let's attach the event listner to the document
        document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This solution essentially does the same thing as what I do but the issue is that I get a "Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function". Do you know of a way of solving that?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this SO post: [Youtube API Uncaught TypeError: player.stopVideo is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649268/youtube-api-uncaught-typeerror-player-stopvideo-is-not-a-function). Suggested workaround is to check if you are using another scripts which would messed up the entire YouTube's API.

Here's another reference which might also help: [youtube API playVideo, pauseVideo and stopVideo not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20249948/youtube-api-playvideo-pausevideo-and-stopvideo-not-working)

> First of all, removing the origin parameter will help during development, as it prevents access to the API in general if A) it doesn't match exactly, and B) sometimes for no reason when on localhost.
>
> ...creating a YT.player object consumes a bit of time, and so you then are trying to trigger a playVideo method before the object is fully initialized. Instead you should utilize the onReady callback parameter of the YT.Player object.

Hope this helps!